# If $a^2 + b^2 = 1$, then $a = \sin \theta$ and $b = \cos \theta$ for some $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$. Is there a variation for more than two variables?

Tags: functions, special-functions

Namely, for every integer $n > 2$, are there functions $\phi_1, \dots, \phi_n$ and an interval $[a, b)$ such that: if $a_1^2 + \cdots + a_n^2 = 1$, then there exists a $t \in [a, b)$ such that $a_i = \phi_i(t)$ for $i = 1, \dots, n$?

If not, is there a version of this for at least one integer $n > 2$?

Comment: In general you'll need $n-1$ parameters to describe a hypersurface in $n$-dimensional space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The natural generalization of this situation to higher dimensions is given by generalized spherical coordinates. see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates)

For the $(n-1)$-sphere living in $\mathbb{R}^n$, satisfying the equation $x_1^2+x_2^2+\dotsb + x_n^2=r^2,$ we have coordinates $\phi_1,\dotsc,\phi_n$ which parametrize the sphere via

$$
\begin{align}
x_1&=r\cos\phi_1\\
x_2&=r\sin\phi_1\cos\phi_2\\
x_3&=r\sin\phi_1\sin\phi_2\cos\phi_3\\
\vdots\\
x_{n-1}&=r\sin\phi_1\sin\phi_2\sin\phi_3\dotsb\sin\phi_{n-1}\cos\phi_n\\
x_n&=r\sin\phi_1\sin\phi_2\sin\phi_3\dotsb\sin\phi_{n-1}\sin\phi_n\\.
\end{align}
$$

The polar coordinate $\phi_n$ will be a parameter residing in $[0,2\pi]$ just as in the 1-dimensional case. The rest of the coordinates will have a range only half as big, $\phi_i\in[0,\pi]$, for $1\leq i\leq n-1$.